# SpecFlow StepArgumentTransformation

Tags: specflow

I have Gherkin steps defined like:

```
When I select '<currentuser>'
```

In my stepdefinitions, I would like to capture this parameter and replace this with the one from session. 
I would like to use

```
StepArgumentTransformation
```

here

What is the RegEx expression that I can use to capture everything between `<` and `>`

thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your requirement correctly I don't think you can do what you want. The reason is that there is no transformation from one type to another, its a string in to a string out, which you won't be able to do with a step argument transformation. I think you have a couple of options. 1 is just to use a lookup to the the value from the session in each step. The other is to create a class which can be used in the transform. something like this:

```
public class SessionVariable
{
    ...stuff
} 

[StepArgumentTransformation]
public SessionVaraible TransformToSessionVariable(string input)
{
    ..create session variable from input
}
```

Then make your step methods accept a variable of type `SessionVaraible`

```
[When("I select '(.*)'")]
public void WhenISelect(SessionVaraible sessionVariable)
{
    ...whatever
}
```